# Right Align Columns in Text File with Sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file containing a lot of information that I want to get in a specific format, i.e. add a specific number of spaces between the different columns. I can add the same amount of spaces to every line, but some of the columns need to be right aligned, meaning that I might need to add more spaces in some lines. I have no idea how to do this, and awk doesn't seem to work since I have more than two lines modify.

Here's an example:

I have managed to get a file looking something like this

```
apple   1   33.413 C     cat    10
banana   2   21.564 B     horse    356
cherry   3   43.223 D     cow    32
pear   4   26.432 A     goat    22
raspberry   5   72.639 C     eagle    4
watermelon   6   54.436 A     fox    976
pumpkin   7   42.654 B     mouse    1
peanut   8   36.451 B     dog    56
orange   9   57.333 C     elephant    32
coconut   10   10.445 A     frog    3
blueberry   11   46.435 B     camel    446
```

But I want to get the file on this format

```
apple         1   33.413 C          cat    10
banana        2   21.564 B        horse    356
cherry        3   43.223 D          cow    32
pear          4   26.432 A         goat    22
raspberry     5   72.639 C        eagle    4
watermelon    6   54.436 A          fox    976
pumpkin       7   42.654 B        mouse    1
peanut        8   36.451 B          dog    56
orange        9   57.333 C     elephant    32
coconut      10   10.445 A         frog    3
blueberry    11   46.435 B        camel    446
```

What bash command can I use to right align the second and fifth columns?

Comment: `column -t file` is a good beginning, only that it aligns words to the left

Comment: wrt `awk doesn't seem to work since I have more than two lines modify` - huh? awk works just fine on multi-million-line files. Not sure what you're thinking of with that statement. The term is "align" by the way, not "center". Text can be left-aligned (`foo____`), or right-aligned (`____foo`), or centered (`__foo__`) but the phrase `right centered`as in your question is meaningless.

Comment: @ed-morton this question is case when i will step down with sed - assembly and let awk do for what's created. Or to continue to lose time and to try finding sed solution?? Time is money...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `printf` with width as you want like this:

```
awk '{printf "%-15s%3d%10s%2s%15s    %-5d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}' file
apple            1    33.413 C            cat    10
banana           2    21.564 B          horse    356
cherry           3    43.223 D            cow    32
pear             4    26.432 A           goat    22
raspberry        5    72.639 C          eagle    4
watermelon       6    54.436 A            fox    976
pumpkin          7    42.654 B          mouse    1
peanut           8    36.451 B            dog    56
orange           9    57.333 C       elephant    32
coconut         10    10.445 A           frog    3
blueberry       11    46.435 B          camel    446
```

Feel free to adjust widths to tweak the output.

Comment: it is that kind of problem, nobody can stop you solve it the best.

Comment: what will be the syntax for center allignment? Also for decimal point allignment? Those spaces before %-5d will be printed? Tnx, +1

Comment: Central alignment is little tricky: `awk '{printf "%-15s%3d%10s%2s%*s%*s\t%d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, 10+length($5)/2, $5, 10-length($5)/2,"", $6}' file`

Comment: Thanks! I can see that it is working! However, I have some problems to get the widths correct (my real data doesn't look exactly like the example I gave). Could you explain shortly how s, d and - work?

Comment: [See this tutorial on printf](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)